# Kotlin Reflection get parameter as String

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I know that the title is probably misleading but I have no idea how to name it, so let me describe.

Lets take a simple assertion method

```
fun assertTrue(condition: Boolean) {
  Assert.assertTrue(condition)
}
```

Simple 'useless' wrapper. Then usage:

```
fun foo() {
  assertTrue((bool1 && bool2) || bool3)
}
```

Now in my `assertTrue`  method I want to retrieve string like: `"(bool1 && bool2) || bool3"`. I want to pass this to my logger so:

```
fun assertTrue(condition: Boolean) {
  logger.log("Condition [(bool1 && bool2) || bool3] == $condition")
  Assert.assertTrue(condition)
}
```

Is it possible to get this string via reflection or PsiManager?

Comment: No, that level of detail is lost after compilation.

Comment: The way this usually works is by letting the user pass a message string into the ``assert`` function. Also your function is taking a ``Boolean`` anyway, the actual expression is resolved to a value before the call is made, so the end result can be passed in as a parameter. So the function couldn't have any idea how that boolean was produced anyway. If you wanted to execute that code in the function you could pass in a lambda (with the type ``condition: () -> Boolean``) but like @Tenfour04 says, you lose the information you're looking for here when it's compiled